# invertibility in C*-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I have a question about a passage in the book *C*-algebras and Operator Theory* by Murphy, in the proof of Theorem 2.1.8.

Let $a$ be a hermitian element of a unital C*-algebra and let $\lambda\in\sigma(a)$, and let $b=\sum_{n=1}^\infty i^n(a-\lambda)^{n-1}/n!$, then $e^{ia}-e^{i\lambda}=(a-\lambda)be^{i\lambda}$. Then he says:
Since $b$ commutes with $a$, and since $a-\lambda$ is non-invertible, $e^{ia}-e^{i\lambda}$ is non-invertible. I don't see how the last statement follows.

I tried to proof the invertibility of $a-\lambda$ assuming $(a-\lambda)be^{ia}$ is invertible, but I couldn't. Can you help me? I don't see how the fact that $a$ and $b$ commute are of any help, since that still doesn't imply $a$ commutes with the inverse of $(a-\lambda)be^{i\lambda}$.

Comment: I don't understand why you would try to prove that $a-\lambda$ is invertible if by assumption ($\lambda \in \sigma (a)$) it isn't. What is your question?

Comment: Because the book says the non-invertibility of $a-\lambda$ implies the non-invertibility of $e^{ia}-e^{i\lambda}=(a-\lambda)be^{ia}$, but I don't see why. This is of course equivalent to the statement I tried to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a-\lambda$ commutes with $be^{i\lambda}$. In any ring, if $x$ and $y$ commute and the product is invertible, then each is invertible.

Proof: suppose that $zxy=xyz=I$. Then $zyx=zxy-I$, so $x$ has a left inverse. From $xyz=I$ we know that $x$ has a right inverse. Then $x$ is invertible.